# How to write database creation scripts when coding software setup?

Tags: sql-server

A SQL Server database is part of an software application that clients will install.

When the clients are installing the software, the setup process needs to create an empty database.

Do I need to manually start figuring out which tables needs to be created first, and which foreign key needs to be referenced after X table is created? Or is there a tool that creates these scripts in the correct order using the existing database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can always generate a script of the current database using right-click > Tasks > Generate Scripts in Object Explorer (this should create the tables and keys in the right dependency order). Or you could generate such a script with a 3rd party tool like [Red Gate SQL Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)<sup>1</sup> by comparing the current version of your schema against an empty database. Or you could ship a .bak file (a backup of an empty copy of your database) with your software and the setup could restore it.

*1. Probably dated now, but a few years ago I blogged about many alternatives [here](http://thebertrandfamily.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/).*

Comment: I use the Tasks > Generate Script on the instances I administer. As long as there are no encrypted object, the process runs really smooth. I have heard about using the scripting objects, but without more research, that is not something that I will be using on the job site.

Comment: If you have encrypted objects, then you should be scripting from source control, not from the database.

Comment: In my job, I took on 7 SQL instances and the previous DBA is literally deceased and left no documentation. You are 100% correct in your statement about control source!

Comment: @AaronBertrand "Generate Scripts" was exactly what I was looking for. I selected the one script per object option. It created all the files, but there is no way of telling which script to run first for correct dependency. The other option was one script file for all objects. Is that the only option to create them in right order of dependency?

Comment: @greatbear302 Why do you want each object in its own file? As you've found, they will simply be ordered alphabetically in the output folder (probably all with the exact same timestamp) - not very useful. I don't know of a way to tell SQL Server to script those files out and prepend a number to indicate order.

Comment: @AaronBertrand just thought the one-file option would make one massive file causing reading/editing to be sluggish. But I guess that's not as hurtful as having so many files with no order specific naming convention :)